# TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function

Tags: javascript

so I'm currently making a Discord bot using Discord.JS V13.

I keep getting this error when I run the `node index.js` command

```
TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function
    at module.exports (C:\Users\myUser\OneDrive\Desktop\Green Hosting Discord bot\Handlers\Events.js:10:5)
```

I don't know why it is doing this. The code is:

```js
const { Events } = require("../Validation/EventNames");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const { glob } = require("glob");
const PG = promisify(glob);
const Ascii = require("ascii-table");

module.exports = async (client) => {
    const Table = new Ascii("Events Loaded")

    (await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Events/*/*.js`)).map(async (file)=>{
        const event = require(file);

        if(!Events.includes(event.name) || !event.name) {
            const L = file.split("/");
            await Table.addRow(`${event.name || "MISSING"}`, `⛔ Event name is either invalid or missing: ${L[6] + "/" + L[7]}`)
            return;
        };

        if(event.once){
            client.once(event.name, (...args)=>event.execute(...args, client));
        } else {
            client.on(event.name, (...args)=>event.execute(...args, client));
        };

        await Table.addRow(event.name, "✔ SUCCESSFUL")
    });

    console.log(Table.toString());
};
```

If you could help me, that would be amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
const promise = await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Events/*/*.js`)
promise.map(async (file)=>{
   // code...    
});
```

Or maybe, It's the semi colomn:

```
const Table = new Ascii("Events Loaded");
//--------------------------------------^
(await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Events/*/*.js`)).map(async (file)=>{
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no semicolon after `const Table = new Ascii("Events Loaded")`. The automatic semicolon insertion will only apply if without the semicolon the code would be invalid if concatenated. However here it the code *is* valid (but fails at runtime):

```js
const Table = new Ascii("Events Loaded")

(await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Events/*/*.js`)).map(/*...*/)
```

⬇

```js
const Table = new Ascii("Events Loaded")(await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Events/*/*.js`)).map(/*...*/)
```

As you can see, this would be a function call on the return value of `new Ascii("Events Loaded")`. However, that isn't a function and can't be called, hence the error.

The solution is therefore to add the missing semicolon here:

```js
const Table = new Ascii("Events Loaded");
//                                      ^
```

Or, if you want to write code without semicolons, you instead need to [insert a semicolon at the *start* of lines if they begin with certain characters](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unexpected-multiline) including `(`, as is the case here:

```js
;(await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Events/*/*.js`)).map(/*...*/)
```